# How to change the base link url in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, base-url

have changed the Base Link Url(base link url) ( not the base url) . Now my site is not accessible except for the home page. How to solve this ? . This option is not visible in core_config_data table too.

I am using magento 1.9

I changed it

```
system -> web -> unsecured -> base link url .
```

Now I am not able to access anything in my site. as am getting two index.php in the url.

Answer (score 5):

You need to have access to your database (command line or phpmyadmin)

```
Select * from core_config_data where value like 'http%';
```

You will be able to find your urls. Make note of your config_id's

You can now up date the URLs you need

```
Update core_config_data set value = 'http://www.domain.com/' where config_id in (list your id's here);
```

**ALWAYS BACK UP FIRST**

Answer (score 3):

You need to check base link of site.

```
select * from core_config_data where path  like '%base_link_url%'
```

If it not proper then you need to change base link.

```
update  core_config_data set value ='http://yousiteurl' where path  like '%base_link_url%'
```

As for index.php check  `Apache mod_rewrite enable` and  check `magento seo engine is enable or not`.if it not enable then you need  to enables

```
 update  core_config_data set value =1 where path  like '%use_rewrite%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple,

goto your phpmyadmin,

select your database,

find table core_config_data,

then select this table,

and find web_unsecure_url and web_secure_url . for both paste your site url with / at last.

Answer (score 0):

ummm - all good advice IF the O.P. had not said that he needs to edit base LINK url - which is NOT in core_config_data...

I have the same issue - even though i can manually edit the path to remove the second 'index.php/' entry - which gets me to the admin panel page to edit the base link url entry (removing the index.php from the entry - i can't save the configuration, since it fails and redirects to 404 (because it tries to save to a path including ... index.php/inex.php/...   - so i guess that the O.P. has (had)the same problem ... i need to edit the base LINK url outside of magento

Answer (score 0):

To change the Base Link URL without access to the admin web gui see the following steps.

You can edit `vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Store.php` from your Magento root directory.

Change `public const XML_PATH_SECURE_BASE_LINK_URL = 'web/secure/base_link_url';

public const XML_PATH_UNSECURE_BASE_LINK_URL = 'web/unsecure/base_link_url';`

to `public const XML_PATH_SECURE_BASE_LINK_URL = 'web/secure/base_url';

public const XML_PATH_UNSECURE_BASE_LINK_URL = 'web/unsecure/base_url';`

Then the usual:
`bin/magento setup:upgrade`
`bin/magento setup:di:compile`
`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`
`bin/magento c:f`

Once you are able to get in to the back end, fix your settings then revert the changes to `vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Store.php`

And re-run the `bin/magento` commands above.